# yaml - add key value pair as single yaml anchor

Tags: terraform, yaml

I am working on a yaml file that is utilized by a terraform code for adding tags to multiple Azure resource groups. How can I use yaml anchors here to avoid repeatedly add same set of tag values to multiple resource groups.

I have tried the below code but that is not working.

```
commontags : &commontags
 Tag1: value1      
 Tag2: value2
 Tag3: value3
 Tag4: value4

 tags:
  Tag5: value5
  Tag6: value6 
  *commontags
```

After adding the yaml anchor, the file is not recognized and getting error - `Call to function "yamldecode" failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html). This was defined as optional extension for YAML 1.1, which has been superseded by YAML 1.2 over 10 years ago.

I can't tell you for sure whether terraform supports this, but try it out:

```yaml
commontags : &commontags
  Tag1: value1      
  Tag2: value2
  Tag3: value3
  Tag4: value4

tags:
  <<: *commontags
  Tag5: value5
  Tag6: value6
```